# Why is my Python script running twice in the background when I try to execute it at startup of my Raspberry Pi by adding the command to /etc/profile?

Tags: python, linux, unix, raspberry-pi, startup

Why is my Python script running twice in the background when I try to execute it at startup of my Raspberry Pi by adding the command to /etc/profile?

I have a command written at the end of the file /etc/profile for a Python script to run at startup of my Raspberry Pi, "sudo python /path/filename.py &", and for some reason it runs twice, every time. When I comment the line out and execute it manually from the command line it runs normally. Why does that happen and what can I do to prevent that from happening?

I know for fact that it is running twice in the background because in my code I have a buzzer that beeps twice at times and 3 times at others, and it beeps 4 times instead of 2 and 6 times instead of 3. Also the code ends up contradicting itself, clearly because each script run is trying to do something else at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be better on the raspberry pi stack exchange?

Comment: Are you sure you want your script to start using /etc/profile? Anyway, try debug this by creating a log file. I can think of many reasons why you buzzer misbehaves and not all includes the script running twice.

Comment: Probably should be on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: /etc/profile is not a good place for startup scripts - it gets executed on every shell startup as it is where shells keep their profile settings. Make it into a service and add it to a runlevel instead.

Comment: Sorry guys this is my first post/question. I did not know that there was a dedicated area for Raspberry Pi related questions.

Comment: danny - I would love to do that. I know how to write bash code/scripts, but I don't know how to make it into a service or make the system run it at startup. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question with a better method for running scripts at boot/startup.

I'm not exactly sure why this was happening, but I did learn that executing scripts on startup with this method is a bad practice and is best avoided.

I started using the Crontab instead.

This is what you need to do:

> crontab -e

This opens up the crontab, then add the following line:

> @reboot python /filelocation/filename.py

This will execute the script as soon as the Pi boots up.

No more double script runs!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have VNC enabled? I think that's the problem. It was for me.

See this related discussion:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=59285

So you can disable VNC, do the run levels danny suggested, create a new user (different to the one used for VNC) or start doing this sort of stuff in your script:

```
if [ x"$ALREADY_DONE" == x"" ]; then
    export ALREADY_DONE=yes
    foobar
fi
```

Comment: I don't have VNC enabled. The way I got around the issue was to start my boot scripts somewhere else, as many people suggest that using /etc/profile to do that is not recommended. I'm using "crontab -e" instead and wrote "@reboot sudo python /filelocation/filename.py" and it works great. Thanks for you input!